# sql insert statement sometimes working other times not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, web-hosting

Im building an application and Im having a bizarre issue where sometimes an sql statement will work and the very next call the exact same sql statement simply will not work.

I personally suspect its the hosting provider Im using maybe just not being fast enough to accept large volumes of sql calls to the database, but I figure I will atleast ask to see if anyone else has ever had similar issues

Comment: You'll really need to give us more information about this.  For example, the query you're running, your table structure, your definition of "doesn't work" (i.e. is it throwing an error, failing silently, etc).

Comment: whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: this is the query I run, pretty standard, and works fine most times its runs mysql_query("INSERT INTO tweets VALUES('','$id','$twtid','','$twtsrc','$inreplyto_id','$inreplyto_screenname','$twtext','$pbuid','$pbrname','$pbsname','$pbprfpic')");

Comment: it fails silently but however I havent set up anything error catching wise tbh, whats the best one to use? insert(etcetcetc) or die() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the values you are dynamically adding to the query statement. You should escape the values to make sure they do not break your query.

In PHP you can use the mysql_escape_string() function. Documentation here: https://www.php.net/mysql_escape_string

Also if you are running the query from a browser, you can normally see the error if you do something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("QUERY", $db_connection) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I think you may be right, here is the error I was able to retrieve: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EM WHY YOU MAD, SON. TELL 'EM WHY YOU MAD!','23883319','cabbie richards','therea' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have access to the mysql general query log if you're on a shared host and can't modify the database's my.cnf file, you might draft up a function along the lines of:

```
function dbInsertQuery($query, $conn) {
     $logFile = "/path/to/file.txt";
     $isProd  = FALSE;

     // run your security checks on the query here

     $mysql_query($query, $db_connection) or trigger_error(mysql_error());

     if (!$isProd && is_writable($logFile)) {
       if (!handle = fopen($logFile, 'a')) {
         echo "cannot open dbInsertQuery's log file: " . $logFile;
         exit;
       } 

       $logLine = date(DATE_RFC822) . " - " . $query;

       if (fwrite($handle, $logLine) === FALSE) {
         echo "cannot write to dbInsertQuery's log file: " . $logFile;
         exit;
       }

       fclose($handle);
     }

   }
```

This will allow you to log all your queries to a log file.  I set in a `$isProd` variable for you to toggle for development, and if it is set to the a value of `TRUE`, it won't log to the file, and will skip the who fopen process entirely.  You may need to adjust it, and could even get it to run every query and not just inserts if you wanted.